# Insert conflicts when i'm trying to add a new user in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, localdb

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

```
Source Error: 
Line 153:            {
Line 154:                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
Line 155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);
Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded)
Line 157:                {
```

- The schema looks like this: [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/k57rx.jpg
- The error    message: [2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdzQg.jpg

When i'm trying to register a new user, it throws the error. I kind of know the problem is, but i don't know how i should modify the schema so it doesn't whine when the intersection table is empty. It's my first ASP.NET pet project so please be gentle :)

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [foreign Key Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) in your Library [SQL] Database that does not allow you to add a user unless the key constraint is met. *"The FOREIGN KEY constraint is used to prevent actions that would destroy links between tables."*

From what you described it appears that you cannot add a user without a book intersection.  Check your Key Constraint FK_ASPNet_USerBookIntersection to make sure.

To Fix this you can either delete the FK constraint from your sql table, or provide a default entry in the UsersTable when creating a new user.  Or you could allow nulls on the field that has the FK defined in Users then set that field to null.

Sorry But I can't tell from the diagram which of the two Intersection Columns has the Constraint FK_ASPNet_USerBookIntersection on it that you would need to change.  But one of these should be set to a default value or NULL.